# Наследование обобщенного интерфейса

Tags: c#

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
public interface IIdentifiable<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public interface ILinkable<TKey>
{
    TKey MasterId { get; set; }
    void Link(TKey masterId);
}
```

Я хочу создать интерфейс `IEntityLinkable`, где в качестве параметра будет использоваться класс, реализующий интерфейс `IIdentifiable`. Я могу это сделать так

```
public interface IEntityLinkable<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : IIdentifiable<TKey>
{
    TKey MasterId { get; set; }
    TEntity Master { get; set; }
    void Link(TEntity entity);
}
```

Вопрос в следующем: можно ли средствами языка c# (8 версия), не используя второй параметр в интерфейсе `IEntityLinkable`, использовать параметр из обобщенного интерфейса `IIdentifiable`? Без рефлексии. Использовать `object` вместо `TKey` тоже не хотелось бы.

```
public interface IEntityLinkable<TEntity> where TEntity : IIdentifiable<TKey> where TKey : class
{
    TKey MasterId { get; set; }
    TEntity Master { get; set; }
    void Link(TEntity entity);
}
```

Чтобы можно было написать такой код:

```
public class Product : IIdentifiable<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DictionaryProduct : IEntityLinkable<Product>
{
    public int MasterId { get; set; }
    public Product Master { get; set; }

    public void Link(Product entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделать ровно то, что вы хотите, нельзя. Таков синтаксис.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk спасибо, так и предполагал